# How is reputation supposed to be affected by undelete?

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers

**Problem**
I recently made a post that was deleted by the moderators for being only a link (still learning what's acceptable).
My post: [Create A Magnifying Glass Effect For All Webpage Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178516/create-a-magnifying-glass-effect-for-all-webpage-content/34072487#34072487)

I received 2 downvotes on the answer before it was deleted. I received -4 rep for the downvotes, but then +4 for the deletion (even though I was not the one to delete the answer). Later, I edited my answer and requested an undelete. Upon undelete the - 4 rep hit my account again even though this answer is entirely different from the first, and shows a 0 for the upvote/downvote interface.

Current Votes:
[image: current votes]

---

Current Rep for Answer:
[image: Rep on answer]

**Questions**

- Why do I receive positive rep when another user deletes my answer?
- Why does the negative rep from downvotes on the previous answer show in my feed (and affect my current standing), but not on the interface feature upon undelete?
- Is this a bug or just the way the site functions?

**Explanation**
I do not think that this post is effectively explained by the post: 
[How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
It does not explain why the negative rep persists and why the UI is unchanged.

Comment: @rene -Thanks for the link, but I do not think it effectively explains what is going on here. There is no explanation for how undelete transfers negative rep and how the UI is influenced. Similar questions are asked in the comment section, but left unanswered (see Jason C comment).

Comment: @ITSUUUUUH Sure it does, look at the accepted answer at the part how deletion and undeletion affects your reputation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  It explains my first question, but not the other 2. That was the point I was trying to make. I also wanted to know if there was some correlation between which user deletes the post (like if you delete it you benefit, but if someone else has to delete it you are given negative rep). But apparently there isn't from what I'm seeing here.

Comment: @ITSUUUUUH If you would have deleted/undeleted it yourself you would have seen the exactly same effect. You just can't undelete it simply, if it wasn't you that deleted your question. Also you should note, that deleting your downvoted questions, may give you the rep back, but if doing so too often this action may count against you with a question ban. The almost always better (and encouraged) action instead of deleting your downvoted posts, is to edit them for improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reputation has to be inline with your visible, non-deleted posts.

That answer has two down votes:

[image: vote breakdown]

On an answer, a down vote costs you 2 reputation. Given the 2 down votes that would mean a subtraction of 4 reputation.

When you delete the answer the post no longer is part of your reputation calculation. So you get the earlier subtracted 4 reputation back, so your rep goes up.

When you undelete the answer the two down votes come again back in play, so the 4 reputation points are subtracted again.

That the score was not correctly reflected after undeletion might have been caused by caching. Refreshing the page should have fixed that.

The score is not reset when you delete, edit and undelete the post. That would be too easy to exploit to get rid of down votes.

Comment: I'm still not able to see the number of downvotes, but thank you for the clarification. Maybe it will refresh later today...

Comment: Change has been reflected, that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It was worrying me since it had been a day with no change

Comment: Well actually the answer has two upvotes so the score is correct